# Is there a faster way to check if user in authenticated or not? (NextJS + Next Auth)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I have developed a small website using the next-auth library, which has worked as expected 99% of the time. However, I encountered an issue with rendering items in the navigation bar based on the authentication status, which led me to implement a conditional statement that displays item 1 if authenticated and item 2 if not authenticated. Unfortunately, on page refresh, none of the items were rendered until the user's authentication status was confirmed, which prompted me to add an additional condition to display item 1 if the page was still loading. The issue with this approach is that, even when the user is logged in, item 1 is displayed first (due to the loading condition) before switching to item 2...

To address this issue, I sought an alternative solution and decided to use the original NextJS repository with pre-made authentication using NextAuth: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-example. However, this repository displayed the same behavior (albeit with a fancy transition) as my previous implementation.

I have been unable to identify a faster way to confirm the user's authentication status to improve the rendering of the navigation bar. It is important to note that the code used for the implementation is identical to the original code in the NextAuth repository without any modifications.

The original code used in the NextAuth repository to check the user's authentication status is as follows:

```
const { data: session, status } = useSession()  
 {!session && (
      // no sign-in component
 )}

 {session?.user && (
      // signed-in component
 )}
```

The approach I initially used is as follows:

```
const { status, data } = useSession();

{status === 'unauthenticated' && (
     // no sign-in component
)}

{status === 'loading' && (
     // loading component which was the no sign-in component
)}

{status === 'authenticated' && (
     // signed-in component
)}
```

Comment: Still couldn't find anything... Tried to use "getServerSideProps" and pass the session (from index) to layout, then to header (that's the structure in the repository), but, I couldn't log the session in the header.

Comment: I can't answer really, but as far as I can see you need to read user specific data, so 2 options: Read the data from the HTTP request (e.g. I know you can read cookies from a [next.js middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware), or accept that the page needs to load client data on runtime, and add fallback components for the time before the client code is executed.

Comment: This is what I did: created a function in every page (getServerSideProps), then passed it inside the page as a prop, then, send it to layout > header.

I did get what I want, but I'm not sure if it's the best approach (having a getServerSideProp inside each page, and send it as a prop to layout then header).